# React-native - get user settings

Tags: react-native, settings

Is there a way to get user settings in react-native (both iOS and Android) ? For example, I would like to show the user's contacts with the chosen sorting preferences (last name - first name, or the opposite)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you can use React-Native's [Settings](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings) which is a wrapper for [iOS nsuserdefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults).

For accessing some system settings like volume, brightness, location, you can use [react-native-system-setting](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting).

If you want to access the user's contacts, have a look at [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts).

Comment: how about user calendar ?